# Sql Query Convertion into Linq Query In Wcf Servive

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

Linq Query provides better readability and compilation error advantages . I have basic knowledge to write Linq  query but there are some Sql queries is very complicated to convert into Linq . Here is one , I am facing good amount of pain to convert it into Linq .How can I write below Sql query to Linq .

```
public bool CurrentAccountDepositDetails(Current_Account_Deposit_Details current_Account_Deposit_Details)
        {
            int j = Convert.ToInt32(current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number);

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {

                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT(*)FROM Current_Account_Details");
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", depositDetails.Account_Number);


                SqlTransaction trans;
                cn.Open();
                trans = cn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Current_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance +'" + current_Account_Deposit_Details.Amount + "' where Account_Number ='" + current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number + "'";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", depositDetails.Account_Number);

                j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    trans.Commit();


                    //Create the SqlCommand object
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Current_Account_Dposit", con);
                    //Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
                    cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //Add the input parameters to the command object
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Name", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Holder_Name);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Amount);


                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort_Code", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Sort_Code);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transcation_Type", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Transcation_Type);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Date);



                    //Open the connection and execute the query
                    con.Open();
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    return true;

                    //Retrieve the value of the output parameter
                }
                else
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }



            }
        }
```

Any suggestion or feedback or help would highly appreciated ...

Comment: Use Dapper(mini ORM) if you would like to play with objects

Comment: sorry what you really mean ???/

Comment: I mean, you can use Dapper library which will serves as mini Object Relational Mapper. You can create your database table as class and you can pass that type to update and select whatever operation you would like. You can go through http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper tutorial

Comment: You want one Linq query to run a select and and update and a stored procedure? And by "Linq" do  you mean Entity Framework? Because Linq itself does not work on databases.

Comment: Yes. select , update ,delete with entity framework but I am not sure about transaction like above one@Crowcoder

Comment: is it possible ?@

Comment: yes it is possible to use transactions and easy to convert them to Entity framework.

1) start with adding the db objects into entity framework ( ADO.NET Entity Data Model)
2) Start using linq/lambda as you wish. 
3) use the Database.BeginTransaction()  and context.commit/rollback accordingly.

To answer your question yes it is possible . Post the code after you make this changes. And that will be easy to look into.

Comment: I already added the ADO.NET Entity Model

Comment: but the problem is how I will start write linq query for above example . I am so confused

Comment: what is the linq query for this sql ..... cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Current_Account_Details set Account_Balance=Account_Balance +'" + current_Account_Deposit_Details.Amount + "' where Account_Number ='" + current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number + "'";

Comment: change the object values and call the save changes

Comment: var foundAccount= dbContext.Current_Account_Details.where(x=> x.id==given_id);
foundAccount. AccountBalance = your_balance_from_variable;
dbContext.SaveChanges()

This is to explain how to do it. The code may not compile

Comment: what I should use for this variables in linq......  SqlTransaction trans;
                cn.Open();
                trans = cn.BeginTransaction();

Comment: Will share the pseudocode as a seperate answer.

Comment: ok.thanks very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155469/discussion-between-pon-saravanan-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use transactions 
and easy to convert them to Entity framework. 
1) start with adding the DB objects into entity framework ( ADO.NET Entity Data Model) 
2) Start using LINQ/LAMBDA as you wish. 
3) use the Database.BeginTransaction() and context.commit/rollback accordingly.

The below code is just to give you an idea. May not compile

**Code**

```
public bool CurrentAccountDepositDetails(Current_Account_Deposit_Details current_Account_Deposit_Details)
{
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number);

    using (MyDbContext  ctx = new MyDbContext(ConnectionString))
    {

        var foundAccount = ctx.Current_Account_Details.firstOrDefault(x=> x.Account_Number == j);

        using (var dbContextTransaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        { 
           var acctDetails= ctx.Current_Account_Details.firstOrDefault(x=> x.Account_number =depositDetails.Account_Number );
           acctDetails.Account_Balance ==  acctDetails.Account_Balance +current_Account_Deposit_Details.Amount ;

           if(acctDetails!=null)
           {
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                //do your deposits here similar to accdetails
                //ctx.Current_Account_Dposit()storedprocedure if you included while creating db file
            }               
            else
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is an operation with + sign in code as you know to update account balance ?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your valuable time . Let me compile and run it what the result I get from it

Comment: acctDetails.Account_Balance == acctDetails.Account_Balance +current_Account_Deposit_Details.Amount ; 

On this line where I should use + or - sign to update account balance ?